# Generic type-safe util to convert High Order Components to Render Prop Components

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I am trying to write a Util which converts any HOC into a [Render Prop Component](https://react.dev/reference/react/cloneElement#passing-data-with-a-render-prop)

For example, it should work like this:

```js
  type HOC<In, Out> = (C: React.ComponentType<Out>) => React.ComponentType<In>
  type User = { id: string } // Some example model
  // @ts-expect-error Some example HOC, ignore the implementation it's just a mock which doesn't work
  const withUserFromId: HOC<{ userId: string }, { user?: User }> = C => C

  // Converted to Render Prop
  const WithUserFromId = convertHOCToRenderProps(withUserFromId)

  // Example usage:
  function App() {
    return (
      <>
        <WithUserFromId userId="1" render={({ user }) => <Text>{user?.id}</Text>} />
      </>
    )
  }
```

I actually have a semi working solution, the JavaScript does what I want and it works with some HOCs that I've tested:

```js
export type HOC<In, Out> = (C: React.ComponentType<Out>) => React.ComponentType<In>

export type WithRenderProps<In extends {}, Out extends {}> = React.FC<
  In & { render: (props: Out) => React.ReactNode }
>

/**
 * Converts a Higher-Order Component (HOC) to a Render Prop component.
 * @param {HOC} hoc - A Higher-Order Component to be converted to a Render Prop component.
 * @return {React.FC} A Render Prop component.
 * @example
 *
 * const WithUserFromId = convertHOCToRenderProps(withUserFromId)
 *
 * <WithUserFromId userId="1" render={({ user }) => <Text>{user?.id}</Text>} />
 */
export const convertHOCToRenderProps = <In extends {}, Out extends {}>(
  hoc: HOC<In, Out>
): WithRenderProps<In, Out> => {
  const RenderPropContext = React.createContext<(props: Out) => React.ReactNode>(() => null)
  const useRenderProp = () => React.useContext(RenderPropContext)

  function Inner(outProps: Out) {
    const render = useRenderProp()
    return <>{render(outProps)}</>
  }
  const EnhancedInner = hoc(Inner)
  const Outer: WithRenderProps<In, Out> = (
    props: In & { render: (props: Out) => React.ReactNode }
  ) => {
    return (
      <RenderPropContext.Provider value={props.render}>
        <EnhancedInner {...props} />
      </RenderPropContext.Provider>
    )
  }
  return React.memo(Outer)
}
}
```

However I'm trying this with `@nozbe/with-observables` and it's not correctly inferring types for example:

```
const withProfile = withObservables<{ profile: Profile }, { profile: Profile }>(
    ['profile'],
    ({ profile }) => ({ profile })
  )
  const WithProfileFromId = convertHOCToRenderProps(withCalendarFromId)
  //    ^? WithRenderProps<Omit<{}, never> & { profile: Profile; }, {}>
```

Thanks for any pointers.